# What decides the size of a 'div' without setting the width and the height?

Tags: css

Provided a float mode set, if the content of the div (eg. img) has width and height. Does the size of div change to adapt its content, or remains as 0.

Answer (score 10):

By default a `div` is a block element, it means its width will be 100% of its container width, and its height will expand to cover all of its children.

In case its children has a larger width than the `div`'s container width, the `div` itself does not expand horizontally but its children spill outside its boundary instead. This is based on the `div`'s default `overflow: visible;` setting.

*Edit based on question change*:

- If the `div` is floated, yes its width and height will expand to cover
  its children.
- If the children are floated, the `div`'s dimension remain at 100% container's width and 0 height.

Comment: _"this is based on the div's default `overflow: auto;` setting."_ - isn't `overflow: visible` by default?

Comment: Oh you're right Vucko! Thanks I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look to this code.

```
<div style='border:10px solid black;'>
    <img src="https://wakeuptiger.files.wordpress.com/2014/06/77-yoda-star-wars-may-the-force-be-with-you2.jpg" alt="Smiley face">
</div>
```

View this example on [`jsFiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/spidiweb/4L40gwj6/1/), you can differentiate inner content and div's width by seeing the border

The width of the div is by default 100% (due to `display:block` css) and the height vary according to the inner content.

Also, the width will always remain 100% even if inner content has higher width.

Comment: Why post an answer with the same solution already posted? This will likely give you down votes.

Comment: The time I posted the answer, the other options wer not showing.

Comment: The first came in more than a minute earlier, likely the same time you started writing yours, still, when one see another answer posted before your own with the same solution, you should delete yours.

Comment: OK. Will keep it in mind for next time. Deleting this will delete the associated example too. So, not deleting this for now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the size of the div adapts.

If you do not specify dimension of the div it adapts to the size of its content.

Comment: If it is under the "float" mode, can it be changed?

Comment: it adapts even if the div is floating

Comment: Why post an answer with the same solution already posted? This will likely give you down votes.

Comment: the answers were posted at the same time

Comment: The first came in more than a minute earlier, likely the same time you started writing yours, still, when one see another answer posted before your own with the same content, you should delete yours, and definitely when it is a more descriptive answer.